# How to pass authToken to public upstream source in azure artifact feed?

Tags: npm, azure-devops, continuous-integration, devops, azure-artifacts

I have a feed in azure devops that is set up with upstream sources but one of the upstream sources requires an authToken for access.

In my app in the .npmrc I can normally do

@scope:registry:[registryUrl]
[url]:_authToken=[token]

this passes the token to the registry.

In azure devops when setting up an upstream source for a feed there is no way that I can see to pass up a token that is used when accessing that source, has anybody came across this problem before?

There doesnt seem to be any documentation I can find of passing up an auth token to an upstream source in azure devops feeds.